# .Net Standard 2.0 CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths fails

Tags: c#, razor, .net-standard-2.0, .net-core-2.2

TL;DR; Is there anyway to tell CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths where to look for the references?

I've tried modifying the current working directory and even tried modifying the current AppDomain base directory to no avail.

---

So my team is currently using RazorLight to handle message templating in a .Net Core 2.2 console application.

I have added RazorLight 2.0.0-beta1 to a .Net Standard 2.0 library and created an interface for it.  However, we discovered there was a conflict with a different library we were using due to that library using a C DLL.  To solve the conflict we opted to remove the other library using the C DLL as no one had been using it's functionality yet.  However, now we are at a point where we need both.

Luckily, RazorLight allows you to specify an assembly to use as the root.  So I created a basic empty library project (RazorScope), that has no libraries other than RazorLight and our Models library.

RazorScope has the PreserveCompilationContext flag to true in it's csproj.

I have a pre-build event on our console app to publish RazorScope to the solution root/RazorScope folder and then a post-build and post-publish event that copies the RazorScope publish into the console app build/publish.  I chose to go this route due to the "refs" folder that PreserveCompilationContext creates and I wanted to keep things clean.  If I just add RazorScope as a project reference to the console application, it doesn't pull in those refs or the json.deps file for RazorScope...

The issue is that when RazorLight eventually calls CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths, it fails b/c it refuses to look in the RazorScope folder in the bin/publish directory and expects everything to be directly in the base directory.  If I move the refs and other files up to base, it works fine, but now I've dirtied my console task bin/publish directory.

Is there anyway to tell CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths where to look for the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is just to not use the RazorLightEngine Nuget package.  It's not really being maintained regularly anyway.

I ended up just rolling my own Roslyn compilation instance after using the .net core razor library to generate the c# code.